# する際 and 穴埋め meaning along with として

Tags: translation, syntax

> 初めは番組を編成する際の穴埋めとして放映されていたのだが、番組の数が増え,年月を経るうちに、子どもたちにとって生まれたときから存在しているアニメは、今やなくてはならない娯楽となっている.

My attempt to translate that would be something like

> In the beginning, when broadcasts were created by filling the gap
>   (???) were televised but, as they grew in numbers and time past,
>   the anime that existed since when we were born as kids, they became a
>   must amusement.

which is incomprehensible for me. The key seems to be the clauses in the title but I figured out midways that the translation of the last part with kids being raised with animes e.t.c. doesn't really make sense too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse it like this:

> 初めは[{(番組を編成する際の)穴埋め}として]放映されていたのだが、

番組を編成する際の modifies 穴埋め, "fillers (between programs) used when editing TV programs / planning program schedule." So I think it's like "In the beginning, anime were broadcasted as fillers inserted when organising TV programmes, but..."

> 番組の数が増え、年月を経るうちに、

as they(=TV programs) grew in numbers and time passed,

> 子どもたちにとって(、)[生まれたときから存在している]アニメは、

The relative clause 生まれたときから存在している modifies アニメ. The subject for 生まれた is 子どもたち. **Edit:** I think it'd be more natural to think the 子どもたちにとって modifies (アニメは)なくてはならない娯楽となっている.
"for children, anime, which have existed ever since they were born,"

> 今やなくてはならない娯楽となっている.

... have become an indispensable entertainment by now.

(Sorry I can't translate it into natural English, but hopefully this might be of some help.)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, second thought. 「子どもたちにとって」の修飾する場所が違ったと思うので、編集しました。

Comment: @Choko: How about "when organising TV programmes" for 番組を編成する際の, and "an indispensable entertainment" for なくてはならない娯楽?

Comment: @eltonjohn Thanks, let me incorporate your suggestions in my post if you don't mind.

Comment: @Choko: I don't mind at all. Go ahead if you please.